# Ошибка server error 500

Tags: django

Разместил простой сайт на хостинге (база учета товаров). На локальном сервере все работает хорошо. На боевом периодически вылезает ошибка `server error 500`. Если обновить страницу, то она открывается. Какой-то особенной закономерности не заметил. Разве, что если постоянно куда-то переходить по ссылкам, то все работает корректно, если прерваться минут на 5-10 и перейти по какой-нибудь ссылке, то появится эта ошибка. В чем причина? Если войти в `shell` первый раз и вызвать `all()` или `count()`, то все хорошо, если какой-нибудь `filter`, то ошибка, нужно заново выходить и входить в оболочку.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Я не спец, похоже, связь разрывается с `mysql`. В `settings` установлен атрибут `CONN_MAX_AGE: None`

Comment: 1) логирование что говорит? 2) пользователь - не root?

Comment: хороший вопрос)) Написал в тех поддержку, там сутки молчат уже, похоже не знают в чем дело. А по логированию)), что оно должно сказать? Куда смотреть?

Comment: вошел в shell. Пытаюсь выполнить Product.objects.all()  и вот выдает django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Comment: Дмитрий, я именно об этом. Разберитесь с логированием и обновите текст вопроса (не оставляйте в комментариях). Иначе это бессмертное: «Дорогие учёные. У меня который год в подполе происходит подземный стук. Объясните, пожалуйста, как он происходит». Мало шансов получить ответ.

Comment: ошибка возникает, а файл error.log пустой, поэтому ничего не могу сказать. Если войти в shell первый раз и вызвать all() или count(), то все хорошо, если какой-нибудь filter, то ошибка, нужно заново выходить и входить в оболочку.  Я не спец, похоже, связь разрывается с mysql. В settings установлен атрибут CONN_MAX_AGE: None

Comment: обновите текст вопроса хотя бы этой информацией

Comment: По опыту 500 ошибка вылетает когда происходит ошибка во views.py и дальше по нисхрдящей. Настройте логгирование для джанго через settings.py, добейтесь ошибки и посмотрите на результат в логах джанго

Comment: Спасибо, поработаю в этом направлении

Comment: Все-таки представления, скорее всего, ни при чем, потому что, работая в shell, получая какой-нибудь queryset, первый раз команда срабатывает, а со второго вылезает ошибка.  from app_stock.models import *
>>> Product.objects.all().count()
769
>>> Product.objects.filter(stock__lte=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
тут много всего и в конце django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Comment: Значит курсор или сам коннектор к базе данных сбоит